# WebApi c# rest web service can't pass list of object

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a simple rest full web service to storage data into database.

So this is my code:

```
[Route("InsertActivities")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage InsertActivities(ActivityExecutionDTO u)
{
    try
    {
        if (u != null)
        {
            //TO DO
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is ActivityExecutionDTO class:

```
namespace WebService.Models
{
    [DataContract(Name = "ActivityExecutionDTO")]
    public class ActivityExecutionDTO
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Username", Order = 1)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Password", Order = 2)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "IdClinicalDocument", Order = 3)]
        public int IdClinicalDocument { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "ActivityDetails", Order = 4)]
        public IQueryable<ActivityExecutionDetailDTO> ActivityDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ActivityExecutionDetailDTO class:

```
namespace WebService.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ActivityExecutionDetailDTO
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "IdClinicalDocument"), IgnoreDataMember]
        public int IdClinicalDocument { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name ="IdActivity")]
        public int IdActivity { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "DateExecution"), IgnoreDataMember]
        public DateTime? DateExecution { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Duration")]
        public Int32? Duration { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "CalBurned")]
        public Int32? CalBurned { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "Steps")]
        public Int32? Steps { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So this is the JSON that I pass throught PostMan client:

```
{
    "Username" : "t.g",
    "Password" : "t",
    "IdClinicalDocument" : 63,
    "ActivityDetails" :
    [
        {
            "Id" : 1,
            "IdClinicalDocument" : 63,
            "IdActivity" : 1,
            "DateExecution" : null,
            "Duration" :  150,
            "CalBurned" : 9600,
            "Steps" :  150
        }
    ]
}
```

So if I try to inspect my code this code:

```
u.ActivityDetails
```

is every times null.

The list of activities is null. Where is the error?

Comment: Try `public HttpResponseMessage InsertActivities([FromBody] ActivityExecutionDTO u)`

Comment: For starters, you do not want to pass around IQueryables across tiers. This is not interchangeable with List or Array and exposes the potential for data access from portions of the system not intended to talk to the database

Comment: To add to what @KyleBurns said. Change the DTO to use a concrete `List<ActivityExecutionDetailDTO>` or `Collection<ActivityExecutionDetailDTO>`. It's difficult (if not impossible) to deserialise to a interface type. What concrete instance should the model binder use?

Comment: change IQueryable<ActivityExecutionDetailDTO>  to ICollection<...>

Answer (score 0):

change `IQueryable<ActivityExecutionDetailDTO>` to `ICollection<ActivityExecutionDetailDTO>`

IQueryable stores a query definition only, no data could be in it, but ICollection instead.